# Setting up a read-only user for SVN-Apache

Tags: apache, security, svn

I have followed the directions laid out in the book entitled "Version Control With Subversion" regarding the proper way to set up an Apache based SVN configuration.  So far, I have a "subversion.conf" file in my "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory.  In that file, I have defined a location called "/svn" and have mapped it to the location of my subversion repositories "/x1/svn/(repo1),(repo2),(etc)".  To wit - I have also created a user "svn" that owns the repository area and have added group permissions to Apache so the repositories are accessible from Apache without the need for setting everything owned by Apache (which I think is an odd way to do things).

Anyway.  Here is the issue I am having trouble with.  I would like to set up "a" user that I can hand out to people in the event that I want to allow them to download a copy of the source code of a particular repository code base.  There are a few levels of complexity here.

1. A) allow them a general user that grants read-only access to all the repositories
2. B) provide specific 'read-only' users for specific repositories

Either way, and I imagine it would be easier to explain how to accomplish option (A), how can I do so given the configuration I have set up for my web-server at present?  The following is a copy of my "subversion.conf" file which is working just fine, however requires that any user accessing desired repositories have full access:

```
   <Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /x1/svn

   # Require SSL connection for password protection.
   # In order to do this Apache needs to use a self-signed certificate
   # Talk to Cordel and/or consult Apache Docs and OpenSSL docs
   # SSLRequireSSL

   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion Repository"
   AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-file
   Require valid-user
   </Location>
```

So - how can I add a single general user that would be read-only for all repositories located in SVNParentPath (option A)?  And for extra credit - how can I create unique read-only users for individual repositories (option B).  And all this while retaining the users that must authenticate for full read-write access on all repositories.

I've tried to accomplish this on my own, however, when trying to digest the meaning of the 'Limit' Methods I am confounded by the lack of a straight-forward explanation of which methods are available and what each method actually does in regard to SVN/Apache configuration.  I mean common sense tells me GET is GET (read-only) and that POST is a write operation but this is only common sense.  I've been programming too long to assume that some A-Hole didn't create GET operation with the ability to write data as well.  This is my predicament.  Can anyone shed some light?

Thank You!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look into the [Path Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz) file where you can define a read-only user by using:

```
[/]
username = r
```

or you can define a user for different repositories

```
[repo1:/]
username = r

[repo2:/]
username = r
```

To achieve the above you need to add the following to your Apache configuration:

```
LoadModule authz_svn_module path/to/mod_authz_svn.so
...
AuthzSVNAccessFile /path/to/access/svnaccess
```

Comment: I first had the problem that the repository name was not recognized. The reason was that I used SVNPath and not SVNParentPath in the config file. After switching to SVNParentPath it works nicely!\

Comment: It's also worth [disabling path-based checks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.pathauthzoff) if you don't need them as this will improve performance.